# Do we need the Axiom of Choice to show that $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ are group isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Under the axiom of choice,  $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are both $2^{\aleph_0}$-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. Because they have the same dimension, they are isomorphic as vector spaces. That vector space isomorphism is also a group isomorphism between them.

The proof is clearly non-constructive. Is there a way to explicity construct such an isomorphism, or do we need the axiom of choice?

Comment: Yes. We do. And this is a duplicate. Give me a minute.