# Proving $\langle \Bbb R,+ \rangle \cong \langle \Bbb C,+ \rangle$ without choice

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice, provability

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145163/328173), we have proved that $\langle \Bbb R,+ \rangle \cong \langle \Bbb C,+ \rangle$:

1. Pick your favourite [Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) $H=\{U_\alpha \mid \alpha \in I\}$ where $I$ is an indexing set.
2. Then, $H \cup iH$ is a basis of $\Bbb C$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$.
3. Pick your favourite bijection $\varphi:H \mapsto H \cup iH$.
4. This gives an isomorphism between the two groups concerned.

Choice is used in the 1<sup>st</sup> step and, I believe, in the 3<sup>rd</sup> step.

---

Let $P$ be the proposition $\langle \Bbb R,+ \rangle \cong \langle \Bbb C,+ \rangle$ under $ZF$. Which of the following statements are true?

1. $\vdash P$
2. $\vdash \neg P$
3. $\operatorname{Con}(ZF \cup \{P\})$
4. $\operatorname{Con}(ZF \cup \{\neg P\})$

Comment: Out of the gate, if it is provable from ZFC, then it is consistent with ZF. So option 2 is immediately false; and option 3 is immediate true. Now, 4 holds if and only if 1 fails. And as luck would have it, that is indeed the case.

Comment: Also, c'mon, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424295/do-we-need-the-axiom-of-choice-to-show-that-mathbbr-and-mathbbc was asked *very* recently. Not even a week ago! :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila a gold badge in the axiom of choice...

Comment: I've spent the last seven years working on choice related research. So that kind of makes sense, why not?

Comment: @AsafKaragila that's awesome